# Retraining model in scikit learn Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn

I have a machine learning Random Forest model that predicts a certain variable. It's implemented with scikit learn and it works fine.

Now, assuming that the prediction relates to month 1, I need a new model to predict the variable of month 2, 3, and so on until 12 months. So, what I need is to predict the variable for month N using the prediction of month N - 1.

To do this manually, I would have to process each month in a loop, adding the previous prediction to the historic data, and retrain the model.

The problem is that retraining takes a long time, and I would have to do it 12 times.

Is there a way to "add" to the trained data the new values, without retraining? Or maybe my approach should be different?

Comment: you can freeze the neurons or you can save the weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are interested in [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

It is not possible [as has been stated here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/sklearn-randomforest-online-learning). :-)

[Combining random forest models in scikit learn might be interesting for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489667/combining-random-forest-models-in-scikit-learn).